# How is AWS Athena so different from a database

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

AWS Athena can read tables, create new tables and insert into tables (among other things). Is it fair to say that Athena can replace the basic functions of a database , or is it fair to say that Athena can be seen as a lightweight serverless replacement of a relational DB? What are its major differences compared to a DB ?

Answer (score 2):

Athena is not a **database** and it's a **query engine**.In Athena **compute and storage are separate** where as in the case of a database both are tightly coupled.

Athena is more of a [OLAP](https://olap.com/olap-definition/#:%7E:text=OLAP%20(Online%20Analytical%20Processing)%20is,(budget%2C%20forecast)%20planning.) solution where as relational DB is [OLTP](https://www.guru99.com/what-is-oltp.html) and it is fully managed service. It will also not maintain the metadata and instead use Glue catalog to store and reteive it.

Also found [this](https://www.upsolver.com/blog/comparing-amazon-athena-traditional-databases) article which talks little more about the differences. You can have a read.